# How do you connect Eclipse to Valgrind via WSL on Windows 10?

Tags: valgrind, eclipse-cdt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to do memcheck on C applications on Windows.

My hypothesis is that Valgrind via WSL would also require compiled executable to be done in Linux. Is this setup to be avoided or recommended?

Comment: I don't think Valgrind working for Windows even with WSL. You can try Intel  Vtune instead

Comment: I had mine working earlier. I just wanted the GUI of eclipse to connect to it.

Comment: See: [Run settings](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_arg.htm) i.e. something like `valgrind --tool=cachegrind Debug\my.exe`